# Active Storage Links (AWS-S3) went missing after redeploying the app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

Has anyone encountered this issue where your file links (using Active Storage and AWS-S3) suddenly just go missing after - redeploying/updating your app on Heroku?

I'm currently working on an app using Rails 6, Ruby 2.6 and Postgres. This is the very first time I've experience the missing link issue.

Just to give a clearer picture. The file link is clickable. Hence, it means that `i.e. user.avatar.attached?` returns true.

Upon clicking on the file link, i was returned with the 404 error and message saying page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Was your file successfully uploaded to AWS S3?
Perhaps share your file url ? I am using AWS S3 too and my files has this url: .s3.amazonaws.com , 
Heroku will delete files after a few hours if it is not hosted on AWS

Comment: Hey! thanks for your input. While it was not proven yet but I suspect the cause was due to the sharing of the AWS S3 bucket between my development server and production server (as I have not migrated the AWS S3 bucket for the production - still in midst of debugging). I found that there is background job by active storage to purge aws links that are no longer relevant. So i'm guessing... when i run my localhost, the active storage job will run through the development database

Comment: and it finds that there are a bunch of file links (on S3) that are not relevant (because they are linked to object from production database and proceeded to purge the links.